# Scrapy shell gets 301 redirected to URL without parameters

Tags: python, redirect, scrapy

[Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html) can request URLs with `GET` parameters to interactively explore the response:

```
scrapy shell "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=foo"
```

But with some websites, my request gets `301` redirected and the URL parameters are stripped:

```
DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://foo.com/mypage/> 
  from <GET http://foo.com/mypage/?bar=baz>
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://foo.com/mypage/> (referer: None)
```

When I visit `http://foo.com/mypage/?bar=baz` in my browser as normal I don't get redirected and the `GET` parameters remain.

Can anyone suggest how I might avoid being redirected?

Comment: post whole code and error you got.

Comment: Hey,I have posted the whole code and the output message.

Comment: @user2019135 , try using your browser's User-Agent string, for example  with the [`USER_AGENT` setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent)

Comment: @paultrmbrth I had this exact problem, and your solution solves the problem. Please post as an answer and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by @paultrmbrth's answer in the comments, here's exactly how to get around this problem using [User Agent spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing).

First, find your browser's User Agent string (I did this using http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/ but there may be other ways).

Mine was

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
```

Now in `project_name/items.py` add the following line:

```
USER_AGENT = "whatever the user agent string was"
```

and `scrapy shell "http://foo.com/mypage/?bar=baz"` will work as expected.